# A Patchbay for Anyone Who Is Broke.

Tags: diy, patchbay, organization, creative-spaces

I picked this idea up from some blog or another.

Go to your work and nab a few of those cantilevered paperclips (the ones that really, really hurt when you stick your finger in and let it close). Then do this:

[Ghetto Patchbay #1 http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tReU7Q2gcsU/TZFUMWko_zI/AAAAAAAAABk/bl6Skrm0GAg/s1600/Cable+clips+1+001.JPG](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tReU7Q2gcsU/TZFUMWko_zI/AAAAAAAAABk/bl6Skrm0GAg/s1600/Cable+clips+1+001.JPG)

(In 1,2 and Out 1,2)

And this:

[Ghetto Patchbay #2 http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-AC4PwVcIYyM/TZFUGwYyUZI/AAAAAAAAABg/LVfiN9LCYLE/s1600/Cable+clips+1+002.JPG](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-AC4PwVcIYyM/TZFUGwYyUZI/AAAAAAAAABg/LVfiN9LCYLE/s1600/Cable+clips+1+002.JPG)

Poor Man's patchbay!

The intended application was for USB cables that get used for multiple devices; to keep them from getting their way and falling behind and off the side of your desk.  In this case it works particularly nicely.  You will note that in the top photo, the cables are labelled 1, 2 and Out1, Out2.  Simply put, I've built the world's ghettoest patchbay.  It really is nice, because I use a lot of analog guitar pedals as outboard effects.  This way my I/O, such as it is, is kept tidy, and I don't have to do any reaching around the back of my setup to plug/unplug cables, knocking expensive things over.  Also, I don't have to drop a bunch of money to buy a 36 channel patchbay, of which I'll use maybe 6.  I can expand/contract it as needed at virtually no expense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel that you NEED a patch bay, can't afford to buy one, and are handy with a soldering iron, they're easy enough to build.  A power drill and a couple rack-blanks, followed by a handful of TRS jacks and about 10 ft. of wire, and you're there.

If you're really ambitious, you could wire in a volume pot to every line, which would make your DIY patch bay more functional than a lot of professional ones.

That said, this is an excellent idea for anyone who can't, or doesn't want to, build their own.

Answer (score 1):

I have 4 extra 96 tt if u want one, if u pay to ship i am sure I can send u one. Ryanhdd@yahoo.com

Comment: Wow, @Ryanhdd, that's quite the offer.  They're a little bit above my needs and soldering cabability at the moment.  Thanks though.  I'm sure there's someone on here who could make good use of them.

Answer (score 1):

heeeehee great stuff!